# "npm install" failing on elastic beanstalk, however manual execution works

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39602428/npm-install-on-elastic-beanstalk-fails-unless-manually-executed) and this doesn't seem to be the issue in my case.
I am deploying a django code on elastic beanstalk which uses react. To compile the react files, I run npm install and npm run build which seem to fail. These are specified in the .ebextensions config files.

However if I ssh into the instance and set up the environment and run npm install manually then it works without failing.

I am confused as to what is happening?

Here is the tail of **npm-debug.log**

```
70623 silly install node-sass@4.5.3 /opt/python/bundle/3/app/eb_miral/node_modules/.staging/node-sass-db50db14
70624 info lifecycle node-sass@4.5.3~install: node-sass@4.5.3
70625 verbose lifecycle node-sass@4.5.3~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
70626 verbose lifecycle node-sass@4.5.3~install: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-    bin:/opt/python/bundle/3/app/eb_miral/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/.bin:/opt/pyth$
70627 verbose lifecycle node-sass@4.5.3~install: CWD: /opt/python/bundle/3/app/eb_miral/node_modules/node-sass
70628 silly lifecycle node-sass@4.5.3~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node scripts/install.js' ]
70629 verbose stack Error: spawn ENOMEM
70629 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
70629 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:328:11)
70629 verbose stack     at exports.spawn (child_process.js:369:9)
70629 verbose stack     at spawn (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:21:13)
70629 verbose stack     at runCmd_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:247:14)
70629 verbose stack     at runCmd (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:208:5)
70629 verbose stack     at runPackageLifecycle (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:174:3)
70629 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
70629 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
70629 verbose stack     at chain (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
70630 verbose cwd /opt/python/bundle/3/app
70631 error Linux 4.9.43-17.38.amzn1.x86_64
70632 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--prefix" "./eb_miral/"
70633 error node v6.11.3
70634 error npm  v3.10.10
70635 error code ENOMEM
70636 error errno ENOMEM
70637 error syscall spawn
70638 error spawn ENOMEM
70639 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
70639 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
70640 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

**eb-commandprocessor.log**

```
[2017-09-08T06:18:43.012Z] ERROR [7803]  : Command execution failed: Activity failed. (ElasticBeanstalk::ActivityFatalError)
caused by: npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g

  > node-sass@4.5.3 install /opt/python/bundle/3/app/eb_miral/node_modules/node-sass
  > node scripts/install.js



   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2017-09-08T06:18:43.012Z] ERROR [7803]  : Command CMD-AppDeploy failed!
[2017-09-08T06:18:43.029Z] INFO  [7803]  : Command processor returning results: 
{"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g\n\n> node-sass@4.5.3 install /opt/python/bundle/3/app/eb_miral/node_modules/node-sass\n> node scripts/install.js. \ncontainer_command 03_npm_build in .ebextensions/02_python.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI","returncode":1,"events":[]}]}
```

**.ebextension/01_packages.config** to install node

```
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql93-devel: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []

commands:
    01_node_install:
        cwd: /tmp
        test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/npm ] && echo "npm not installed"'
        command: 'curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && yum -y install nodejs'

files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/00_set_tmp_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm
```

**.ebextensions/02_python.config** for running `npm install`

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python eb_miral/manage.py migrate --settings=miral.settings.production --noinput"
    leader_only: true

  02_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python eb_miral/manage.py createsu --settings=miral.settings.production"
    leader_only: true

  # You can define a build script in packages.json (using gulp, grunt...) to build your client side files
  03_npm_build:
    command: 'npm install --prefix ./eb_miral/ && npm --prefix ./eb_miral/ run build'

  04_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python eb_miral/manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=miral.settings.production"
    leader_only: true # Because it should push everything to cloud only once
```

Adding more details: 
npm version is 3.10.10, node version is 6.11.3, npm registry is https://registry.npmjs.org/ and the architecture is Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Seems like the ENOMEM error occurs quite frequently in deploying to t2.micro instances. It occurs when deployment runs out of memory on the ec2 instance.
Fixed it by adding swap space. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173972/how-do-you-add-swap-to-an-ec2-instance) for more details.